# Validating accounts

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

Im new to ruby on rails and i have been following The Rails Space book to build a social network the problem is that i know from Experience if you dont put in a validator or something you get a ton of fake accounts!

I work better from Examples that i can cut and paste/edit to work with my site i just can seem to find any examples!

Comment: Are you actually asking a question here?  Can you rephrase and be more specific?

Comment: im looking for an example of a registration page that sends the user an email then they have to click the link in the e-mail to confirm there account

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are setting up an authentication system with Rails, I recommend you look at [Devise](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise) ([Railscast episode](http://railscasts.com/episodes/209-introducing-devise)).

Among other things, Devise features email confirmation out of the box.

Comment: I don't think that is what im looking for mabey this will help when you go on facebook and register for the first time it sends you an e-mail with a confermation link in it that takes you to a page that say's you updated your account. That is what im looking for im unshure about this rail cast you sent me to.

Comment: @Rod, check out Devise as Andy suggested--it does what you're looking for ("Confirmable: sends emails with confirmation instructions and verifies whether an account is already confirmed during sign in."). If you'd like a text version of the Railscast Andy mentioned, try: http://asciicasts.com/episodes/209-introducing-devise . Good luck with your project, and be aware if you're new to Rails it may take some time and effort to learn the framework and get things running the way you'd like.

Comment: ive got another problem i have to figure out first b4 i take this one any further